# Changing application CFBundleURLScheme plist entry dynamically (after compilation)

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I'm trying to create an iPhone application that will handle a variety of URL Schemes that I will determine dynamically by querying a server.

Is it possible to register for a custom url scheme programmatically? In other words, can you update the CFBundleURLScheme plist entry after the application has been compiled / deployed?

I haven't been able to find any examples of this being done elsewhere, but nor can I find any definitive reasons why this isn't possible.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, there is no way. You cannot register custom url schemes programmatically. You also cannot edit your Info.plist, application bundles are read-only on the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks ckruse, I expected as much, just wanted some verification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it for Swift:

```
var plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Info", ofType: "plist")

var urlStuff = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath!)
var urlType = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: "com.appprefix.AppName", "CFBundleURLName", NSArray(object: "idofobject"), "CFBundleURLSchemes")
urlStuff?.setObject(NSArray(object: urlType), forKey: "CFBundleURLTypes")
urlStuff?.writeToFile(plistPath!, atomically: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

**NEW ANSWER AS OF 2021**

It is now possible to edit your Info.plist before compiling your app using some scripts.

You can refer to this post: [Add/Replace URL Scheme in Info.plist using bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564263/add-replace-url-scheme-in-info-plist-using-bash-script)