# Add/Replace URL Scheme in Info.plist using bash script

Tags: ios, bash, sed, jenkins, url-scheme

I want to add/replace the URL scheme in `Info.plist` file using bash script/command.

I tried with `sed` command with various patterns but not succeeded.

We want to automate the build generation using Jenkins and our URL Scheme can be changed for various builds, so we want to modify the `Info.plist` file such that we can either add a new URL Scheme if not there or replace the existing one using script/commands.

Please suggest the command to achieve this.

Comment: add some sample of source and result wanted, the regex will depend on surround information. Also provide some unsuccessful sed command (that will help to explain why it failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use awk command to achieve complex things easily instead of sed.

I am able to accomplish the task by the help of "Ed Morton" as in [sed : Insert lines after specific pattern with newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803900/sed-insert-lines-after-specific-pattern-with-newline)

Answer (score 3):

### Task

- set different url schemes for staging/production

### Details

Xcode 9.2

### Solution

**1 create url scheme**

[image]

> in the run script (which is written below) 
>   `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :CFBundleURLTypes:1:CFBundleURLSchemes:0 $SCHEME" "$INFOPLIST_MYAPP"`
>
> we have **:CFBundleURLTypes:1**
>
> 1 = item 1

[image]

**2 add run script**

[image]

```
INFOPLIST_MYAPP="${SRCROOT}/SM2/Application/InfoPlist/Info.plist"
SCHEME=""

case "${CONFIGURATION}" in

    "Debug_Staging" | "AdHoc_Staging" | "Test_Staging" | "Profile_Staging" )
    SCHEME="sm2dev" ;;


    "Debug_Production" | "AdHoc_Production" | "Distribution" | "Test_Production" | "Profile_Production" )
    SCHEME="sm2" ;;

    *)
        ;;
esac

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :CFBundleURLTypes:1:CFBundleURLSchemes:0 $SCHEME" "$INFOPLIST_MYAPP"
```

### All Project Schemes

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use plutil tool

```
$INFO_PLIST_FILE=path_to_your_plist_file

$NEW_URL_STRING=new_url_string

echo "removing current url string"
plutil -remove CFBundleURLTypes.0.CFBundleURLSchemes.0 $INFO_PLIST_FILE

echo "updating with new url string"
plutil -replace CFBundleURLTypes.0.CFBundleURLSchemes.0 -string $NEW_URL_STRING $INFO_PLIST_FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your URL scheme is "myName" then you should have an entry in your info.plist file like:

```
<array>
    <string>myName</string>
</array>
```

You can change `myName` to `newName` with sed like this:

```
sed -i '' 's/<string>myName/<string>newName/' 'info.plist'
```

The `<string>` is important because you probably don't want to replace other `myName` strings with `newName` so it narrows it down.

**Update based on OP comment:**

I am not sure what your info.plist file looks like but here is a general solution. You can make a `template` file of what you like to add to your `info.plist` if the `CFBundleURLTypes` does not exist. For example:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myName</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.xxx.myName</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

So now you have a file called `template` with the previous code in it. To make this only be inserted at the location of first `<dict>`, change your first `<dict>` in the `info.plist` file to `<myDict>`. You can then check if your pattern exists and if it doesn't then insert the `template` and then replace `myName` with `newName` like this:

```
if ! grep -q "<string>myName</string>" "info.plist"; then
   sed -i '' "/<myDict>/ r template" info.plist
else
   sed -i '' 's/<myDict>/<dict>/' 'info.plist'
fi
   sed -i '' 's/<string>myName/<string>newName/' 'info.plist'
```

To make it cleaner you can put the previous code in a bash file `insertURL.bash` and then just run that file.

Comment: Hi Arash, Thanks for the reply. This will work if URL Scheme already there. Can you suggest sed command to check if it is not added then add?

Comment: use a `s///` followed by a `t label` that act like a goto if substitution occur. if label is empty, the goto go to end of script (and treate next line/cycle)

Comment: @patelkavit Updated the answer based on your comment.

Comment: @Arash I tried your updated solution, however it inserts the template code in plist under the line wherever it finds <dict>. This is not correct I want it to be inserted under root dict only. I tried to found an alternate of "r" used in your code without success. Please suggest me.

Comment: @patelkavit I think the `info.plist` I was trying it on only had one `<dict>`. In any case, this is only a matter of find and replace. So you can somehow tag your first `<dict>` with something different. For example replace it with `<myDict>` in the original `info.plist`. Then search and replace only that one. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Arash I can't rename the first <dict> or other tags as Info.plist has its own defined structure otherwise it will not work properly. I tried with different regex but not able to solve the issue. It will be good if you can suggest the solution.

Answer (score 1):

May be useful for others.

I have made run script to add google reverse client at build time according to bundle id:

```
# @usage
# 1. Get reverse client id for google signin according to bundle id
# 2. Set in info.plist file

REVERSE_CLIENT_ID=""

if [ $PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "com.max.bundle1" ]
then
    REVERSE_CLIENT_ID="com.googleusercontent.apps.id1"
elif [ $PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = "com.max.bundle2"]
then
    REVERSE_CLIENT_ID="com.googleusercontent.apps.id2"
fi

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :CFBundleURLTypes:1:CFBundleURLSchemes:0 $REVERSE_CLIENT_ID" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

It works fine for me. To make it work I have added in URL Types at second position like below image:

[image: URL types image]

Here `set :CFBundleURLTypes:1:` is for second URL type as I have already one there. If you have no other url type then you have to write `set :CFBundleURLTypes:0:` in last line. or according to your number of url types.

Just like this you can edit some values like build number in info.plist file at runtime.