# sed : Insert lines after specific pattern with newline

Tags: ios, regex, bash, sed

We want to modify a plist file such that after matching a pattern it should insert few lines using sed shell command.

plist file format is as follow:

```
<plist> 
   <dict>
     .
     .
     <key>abc</key>
     <dict>
        .
        .
     </dict>
     .
     .
    </dict>
</plist>
```

we want to insert few lines after finding the first dict tag.

If I use follow command it inserts after all dict tag in file.

```
sed -i '' "/<dict>/ r template" info.plist
```

So, I tried to find plist and dict tag and insert lines after that.

```
sed -i '' "/<plist version=\"1.0\">\n<dict>/r template" info.plist
```

or

```
sed -i '' "/\(^<plist version=*.\)/ r template" info.plist
```

This also doesn't work for this it is not able to find the pattern in file.

Please suggest me how can I put a pattern which contains two strings separated by newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else just use awk. If you're using anything other than s, g, and p (with -n) in sed then you are using the wrong tool and language constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

There's a lot of ways you could do this. Here's one:

```
$ cat file1
<plist>
   <dict>
     .
     .
     <key>abc</key>
     <dict>
        .
        .
     </dict>
     .
     .
    </dict>
</plist>
```

.

```
$ cat file2
now is the
winter of
our discontent
```

.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{extra = extra $0 RS; next} {print} /<dict>/ && ++count==1{printf "%s", extra}' file2 file1
<plist>
   <dict>
now is the
winter of
our discontent
     .
     .
     <key>abc</key>
     <dict>
        .
        .
     </dict>
     .
     .
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Want to print after the 2nd occurrence of dict instead of the first? Just change `==1` to `==2`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{extra = extra $0 RS; next} {print} /<dict>/ && ++count==2{printf "%s", extra}' file2 file1
<plist>
   <dict>
     .
     .
     <key>abc</key>
     <dict>
now is the
winter of
our discontent
        .
        .
     </dict>
     .
     .
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Want to search for a pattern spanning multiple lines instead of the Nth occurrence of a pattern? Here's one way with GNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' 'NR==FNR{extra=$0;next} {print gensub(/<plist>[[:space:]]+<dict>\n/,"&"extra,"")}' file2 file1
<plist>
   <dict>
now is the
winter of
our discontent
     .
     .
     <key>abc</key>
     <dict>
        .
        .
     </dict>
     .
     .
    </dict>
</plist>
```

All trivial stuff with awk.

To update the original file with any UNIX command is:

```
command file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

so in this case it's:

```
awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

GNU awk has a `-i inplace` argument that works like seds `-i` to create the tmp file behind the scenes if you prefer the marginal brevity:

```
awk -i inplace 'script' file
```

Comment: Great Morton. The awk command you suggested (tried first one) prints the output,however I want to update the plist file (file1 here). It will be good if you can update the command accordingly.

Comment: I added instructions at the end on how to update a file.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '1,/<dict>/{/<dict>/{r template' -e '}}' file
```

Comment: It gives an error  `sed: 1: "1,/<dict>/{/<dict>/{r t ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`  we are using sed on OS X

Answer (score 0):

Try the the 'N'-command to enable newline matching:

```
sed 'N;/<plist>\n\s\+<dict>/a added line' info.plist
```

Comment: It gives an error as ` sed: 1: "N;/<plist>\n\s\+<dict>/ ...": command a expects \ followed by text `