# Insert new line after every semi-colon

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Similar [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803900/sed-insert-lines-after-specific-pattern-with-newline?rq=1) are so complicated and difficult to intepreret; I would have to spend hours learning unnecessary awk, sed, and/or RegEx commands.

So, I have a really long file (foo_In.txt) that is formatted in one huge line, like this:

```
stuff;stuff3;stuff;asdf;fsdf;asdf;sfd;
```

I would like to input foo_In.txt and output foo_Out.txt,

```
stuff;
stuff3;
stuff;
asdf;
fsdf;
asdf;
sfd;
```

I would be able to use scripting languages such as batch, shell, or python.

Comment: do you need ; symbols? if no there is even shorter option tr ';' '\n' <file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do:

```
sed "s/;/;\n/g" foo_In.txt > foo_Out.txt
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for... short and sweet.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v RS=';' -v ORS=';\n' 'NF' file
stuff;
stuff3;
stuff;
asdf;
fsdf;
asdf;
sfd;
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can do it:

```
awk '{gsub(/;/,"&\n")}1' file
stuff;
stuff3;
stuff;
asdf;
fsdf;
asdf;
sfd;
```